# An equality involving binomial coefitients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am wondering why formula
$$\sum_{j=k}^n\binom{n}{j}(-1)^j = (-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k-1} $$
is correct only for $1<k<n+1$. Could it be extended to $0<k<n+1$?

I found this formula [here](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82#.D0.91.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.BC_.D0.9D.D1.8C.D1.8E.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D0.B8_.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B4.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B8.D1.8F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can. If $k=1$ the LHS is equal to $-1$, and the RHS is also equal to $-1$.

Proof:
 $$0=\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j{n\choose j}={n\choose 0}(-1)^0+\sum_{j=1}^n{n\choose j}(-1)^j=1+LHS$$

In fact, it can be extended for *all* k, provided we agree on the common conventions that ${a\choose b}=0$ for $b<0$ or $b>a$, and that empty sums evaluate to 0.

Edit: fixed silly sign error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!